# Django Friend Request system

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a friend request system with Django for a cat app, and I am having a problem. I have models to track the friends and the friend request. In the views I have a redirect view with a try except clause that creates a new instance of the friend request model. Then the friend request will be shown to whoever it was sent to, and they will accept or decline it. The problem I have is i don't know how to grab the info about the user to whom the friend request is sent. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the link to my project repository https://github.com/codewiz9/chatter

modles.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

# Create your models here.
class Chat(models.Model):
    messages = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=2000, null=False),
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, editable=False),
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True,),
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Friend_List'),

class Friend_List(models.Model):
    friend_name = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='name', on_delete=models.CASCADE),
    is_friend = models.BooleanField(default=False),

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Friend_Info(models.Model):
    friend_name = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='name', on_delete=models.CASCADE),
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True,),

class Friend_Request(models.Model):
    yes_or_no = models.BooleanField(default=False),
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Friend_List'),
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True,),
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic
from .models import Chat, Friend_List, Friend_Info, Friend_Request
# Create your views here.

###Genral###
class Dashbord(generic.TemplateView):
    #This classs will have the list of all the users chats
    models = Chat, Friend_List
    template_name = 'chat_app/dashbord.html'


###Friends###
class Friend_Dashbord(generic.ListView):
    #This view will allow users to see thire friends and see thire friend requests and this will contain the button to add new friends
    models = Friend_Info, Friend_List
    template_name = 'chat_app/friend_dashbord.html'

class Friend_Request(generic.RedirectView):
    #This is the form for sending requests S=sent
    models = Friend_Request, Friend_list, Friend_Info
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        friend = get_object_or_404(Friend_Info, slug=self.kwargs.get("slug"))

        try:
            Friend_Request.objects.create(friends=)

class Find_Friends(generic.FormView):
    #this will be the page where you can serch for friends
    models = Friend
    template_name = 'chat_app/dashbord.html'

###Chat###
#the chat portion of the app will be handeled in two parts one will the the form to send the chat and one will be the
#list of all the chats the form view will be inclued on the Chat_list template
class Chat_List(generic.ListView):
    #This will be the list of all the chats sent and resived
    models = Chat
    template_name = 'chat_app/dashbord.html'

class Chat_Form(generic.FormView):
    models = Chat
    template_name = 'chat_app/dashbord.html'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would implement such a model:

```py
class FriendRequest(models.Model):
    # create a tuple to manage different options for your request status
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Pending'),
        (2, 'Accepted'),
        (3, 'Rejected'),
    )
    # store this as an integer, Django handles the verbose choice options
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=1)
    # store the user that has sent the request
    sent_from = models.ForeignKey(User, ..., related_name="requests_sent")
    # store the user that has received the request
    sent_to = models.ForeignKey(User, ..., related_name="requests_received")
    sent_on = models.DateTimeField(... # when it was sent, etc.
```

Now, you will notice that the two user ForeignKey fields have `related_name` attributes, these are reverse accessors and are how you can get related model objects.

Say you have a given `user` object, you can get all of the friend requests they have sent and received using these queries:

```py
# Friend requests sent
user.requests_sent.all()

# Friend requests received from other users
user.requests_received.all()
```

Those provide you with querysets of other users that you can then iterate over and access as needed.